# Visual C# removing a Click event directly after it has been invoked

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio-2013, onclick

I have created a `List` of `PictureBox`'s and during creation attached a click event

```
gameDeckPics[i].Click += (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        // Code to execute on click
                    };
```

With `i` referencing the current index of the `Picturebox` currently being added to the List. When a Click event is used, I move the PictureBox from `gameDeckPics` to another List.  My question is: **How do you remove a Click event from a specific item in a List of items directly after it is clicked?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it when you're creating the method inline like that. Create a separate event method.

```
private void picBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code to execute on click
}
```

Then you can just subscribe and unsubscribe with:

```
gameDeckPics[i].Click += picBox_Click;

gameDeckPics[i].Click -= picBox_Click;
```

If you want to unsubscribe when the click event first fires for a particular `PictureBox`, you could do it from within the click event.

```
private void picBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code to execute on click

    ((PictureBox)sender).Click -= pictureBox1_Click;
}
```

Comment: Ahh perfect, I see now. Elegant solution, thank you! +1